# Python GTK+ 3 pull up just a file chooser dialog?

Tags: python, gtk

I'm trying to create a program that uses the Gtk FileChooserDialog dialog. I followed the tutorial [here](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/dialogs.html#filechooserdialog), and it works. However, I would like to *just* have the dialog pop up and not have to deal with the actual Gtk window.

I've tried taking the code that, in the tutorial, is in the `on_file_clicked()` function and putting it in the `__init__` function (and tweaking it a bit so it *looks* like it would work) after removing the code already in `__init__`:

```
class FileChooserWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        global path

        dialog = Gtk.FileChooserDialog("Please choose a file", self,
            Gtk.FileChooserAction.OPEN,
            (Gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL,
             Gtk.STOCK_OPEN, Gtk.ResponseType.OK))

        self.add_filters(dialog)

        response = dialog.run()
        if response == Gtk.ResponseType.OK:
            print("Open clicked")
            print("File selected: " + dialog.get_filename())
            path = dialog.get_filename()
            dialog.destroy()
        elif response == Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL:
            print("Cancel clicked")
            dialog.destroy()

    def add_filters(self, dialog):
        filter_any = Gtk.FileFilter()
        filter_any.set_name("Any files")
        filter_any.add_pattern("*")
        dialog.add_filter(filter_any)

        filter_text = Gtk.FileFilter()
        filter_text.set_name('Text files')
        filter_text.add_mime_type('text/plain')
        dialog.add_filter(filter_text)

        filter_py = Gtk.FileFilter()
        filter_py.set_name('Python files')
        filter_py.add_mime_type('text/x-python')
        dialog.add_filter(filter_py)

        filter_img = Gtk.FileFilter()
        filter_img.set_name('Image')
        filter_img.add_mime_type('image/*')
        dialog.add_filter(filter_img)

win = FileChooserWindow()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

but it just returns this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "base.py", line 152, in <module>
    win = FileChooserWindow()
  File "base.py", line 38, in __init__
    Gtk.STOCK_OPEN, Gtk.ResponseType.OK))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/overrides/__init__.py", line 175, in new_init
    return super_init_func(self, **new_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/overrides/Gtk.py", line 500, in __init__
    self._init(*args, **new_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/overrides/__init__.py", line 175, in new_init
    return super_init_func(self, **new_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/overrides/__init__.py", line 175, in new_init
    return super_init_func(self, **new_kwargs)
TypeError: could not convert value for property `transient_for' from FileChooserWindow to GtkWindow
```

Does anyone know the proper method for pulling up *just* the Gtk FileChooserDialog dialog?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you declare the dialog on line 6:

```
dialog = Gtk.FileChooserDialog("Please choose a file", self,
```

`self` is the parent of the dialog. To create a dialog with no parent set it to `None`, like so:

```
dialog = Gtk.FileChooserDialog("Please choose a file", None,
```

Answer (score 0):

@Seths solution above crashes with this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scriptname.py", line 57, in <module>
    win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
TypeError: object at 0x7ff81d5dedc0 of type FileChooserWindow is not initialized
CRITICAL: Exiting due to uncaught exception <class 'TypeError'>
```

I found a [simpler PyGObject example](https://athenajc.gitbooks.io/python-gtk-3-api/content/gtk-group/gtkfilechooserdialog.html) and fixed a few bugs to try to get it to work, but it blocks on the main loop and waits:

```
import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk

filechooserdialog = Gtk.FileChooserDialog(title="Open...",
             parent=None,
             action=Gtk.FileChooserAction.OPEN)
filechooserdialog.add_buttons("_Open", Gtk.ResponseType.OK)
filechooserdialog.add_buttons("_Cancel", Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL)
filechooserdialog.set_default_response(Gtk.ResponseType.OK)

response = filechooserdialog.run()

if response == Gtk.ResponseType.OK:
    print("File selected: %s" % filechooserdialog.get_filename())

filechooserdialog.destroy()
```