# Ubuntu | PyCharm | GTK3 | Glade | I have a problem with Gtk.FileChooserDialog

Tags: linux

If I instead use a print function on my defenition, it returns whatever I put in.

Even swear words **(I have tried)**

```
    def on_button1_clicked(self, event):
        print("1")
        dialog = Gtk.FileChooserDialog(
            title="Please choose a file", parent=self, action=Gtk.FileChooserAction.OPEN
        )
```

Whenever I do "the button click", the program returns the following errors

```
 
File "/home/kevin/PycharmProjects/BMWTool/main.py", line 13, in on_button1_clicked
    dialog = Gtk.FileChooserDialog(
  
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/overrides/__init__.py", line 319, in new_init
    return super_init_func(self, **new_kwargs)
  
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/overrides/Gtk.py", line 577, in __init__
    self._init(*args, **new_kwargs)
  
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/overrides/__init__.py", line 319, in new_init
    return super_init_func(self, **new_kwargs)
  
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/overrides/Gtk.py", line 522, in __init__
    _window_init(self, *args, **kwargs)
  
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/overrides/__init__.py", line 319, in new_init
    return super_init_func(self, **new_kwargs)

TypeError: could not convert value for property `transient_for' from Handler to GtkWindow
```

What might I have done wrong? Is there any double paths or something like that maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Searched around a bit more. Found the linked thread.

Solution was to replace parent=self to parent=None

[Python GTK+ 3 pull up just a file chooser dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29977125/python-gtk-3-pull-up-just-a-file-chooser-dialog)